# use condition in case_when() once?

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I have a data frame with multiple time points but I only want to define the first event per time point. F.i., selecting only the first event between 12 months and 24 months and not all.

```
data %>% 
 mutate(
    timepoint_over_time = as.numeric(
      case_when(
      accepted_reduction == "x" ~ "0",
      time_from_injury_months >= 24 & time_from_injury_months < 36 ~ "2",
      time_from_injury_months >= 36 & time_from_injury_months < 48 ~ "3",
      time_from_injury_months >= 48 & time_from_injury_months < 60 ~ "4"
      )
    )
  )
```

I have tried case_when and also if_else but it puts down a value down for each event. Is it possible to only do it once because I want to analyze a timeline?

I have uploaded an example file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0xa1gbbv9kfp14db89a4m/my_data.csv?rlkey=18ylrsteepaobfv0c5uhfi6kq&dl=0)

Comment: Maybe something like `case_when(accepted_reduction == "x" & cumsum(accepted_reduction == "x") == 1 ~ "0", ...` there may be better ways too, but it's hard to know without a little bit of sample data and desired output.

Comment: Since you're using `dplyr` you may want to look into the [`between`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/between.html) function to save you a bit of time

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have added the link to data above.

Answer (score 0):

you can group your data by the corresponding period and then use min to filter your data for the the smallest value within each group:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(time_from_injury_months = runif(100, 24, 59),
               accepted_reduction = sample(c("x", "y"), 100, replace = TRUE))

data %>% 
 mutate(
    timepoint_over_time = as.numeric(
      case_when(
      accepted_reduction == "x" ~ "0",
      time_from_injury_months >= 24 & time_from_injury_months < 36 ~ "2",
      time_from_injury_months >= 36 & time_from_injury_months < 48 ~ "3",
      time_from_injury_months >= 48 & time_from_injury_months < 60 ~ "4"
      )
    )
  ) %>% 
  group_by(timepoint_over_time) %>% 
  mutate(first_point_in_bin = ifelse(time_from_injury_months == min(time_from_injury_months), "yes", "no"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a good idea. The only problem is that it disappears from the main table then. Do you see any other option to write this directly into the main table?

Comment: if you want to keep the shape and just add to data you can use mutate again instead.